# Activity is destroying after trying to start Media player

Tags: android, media-player, nexus-7

Need some help who has experience with media player. On Nexus 7 device after pressing home button(pausing media player), when returning to player from recent list, activity is destroying as soon as start of media player method is called. In other devices seems working good. Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: pause player in  onPause(){ mediaPlayer.pause();} and resume it when your app active again onResume (){ mediaPlayer.start();}

Comment: I already did it, but the problem is on Nexus 7 device. Thanks anyway

Comment: write the answer to all know it or delete your question

Comment: Which answer? I'm still, seeking for an answer..

Comment: you mention the problem in your Nexus 7 device ? or write your error stack to see what cause this problem